# Test outputstream by using InjectMocks

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking

Here is main Class

```
public class ServerConnector {

    private String ipAddress;
    private int portNumber;
    private Socket socket;
    private DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    private DataInputStream dataInputStream;

    public ServerConnector(String ipAddress, int portNumber){
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
        this.portNumber = portNumber;
    }

    public void connect(){
        socket = new Socket();
        InetSocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(ipAddress, portNumber);
        socket.connect(socketAddress, 5000);
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
        dataInputStream = new DataInputStream((new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream())));

    }

    public void send(byte[] sendingData){
        dataOutputStream.writeInt(sendingData.length);
        dataOutputStream.write(sendingData);
        dataOutputStream.flush();
    }

...

}
```

and this is what I want to do for testing send method

```
public class ServerConnectorTest {

    @Mock
    private DataOutputStream mockDataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(null);

    @InjectMocks
    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector("10.10.10.10", 1234);

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<byte[]> byteValueCapture;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Integer> intValueCapture;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Send Data Test")
    void should_send_data_to_server(){
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        try {
            byte[] sendingData = "Test".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            connector.send(sendingData);
            Mockito.verify(mockDataOutputStream).writeInt(intValueCapture.capture());
            Mockito.verify(mockDataOutputStream).write(byteValueCapture.capture());
            int writtenInt = intValueCapture.getValue();
            byte[] writtenData = byteValueCapture.getValue();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I'd like to test connector.send() method but it fails due to dataOutputStream is null.
I could't find what the problem is.. I already found similar inject and mock testing but didn't help.